# Database updates failing

Tags: 8, updating

I sort of inherited a Drupal 8 site which has lately generated a problem causing 500 error when e.g. trying to modify menus. I haven't myself updated the Drupal (just got it, it is currently on version 8.7.5).

I checked what is the status of database and found out there's about two dozens updates needed. So, I though, maybe drush updb would cure the problem. Well, it still might, except that the first update fails and so the others never ever get even tried. The significant lines are as below

> [notice] Update started: feeds_update_8001
>
> [error]  Missing bundle entity, entity type node_type, entity id migrate_example_beer.
>
> [error]  Update failed: feeds_update_8001
>
> [error]  Update aborted by: feeds_update_8001
>
> [error]  Finished performing updates.

How to overcome that? There is no table named migrate_example_beer (though a few others including that part do).

Is it possible somehow to skip the first update, or anyone has any ideas how to cure that one error?

Comment: migrate_example_beer bundle (content type) comes from the migrate example module which comes in the migrate plus module.

Comment: Maybe you have a feed that's suppose to update this beer (content type) bundle, but this content type is missing from your site.

Comment: All the Migrate modules were not enabled and I even uninstalled the  migrate_example_advanced_setup module. And still the same error message :/

Comment: There should be only one feed (which accidentally is written by me) so I can guarantee there is no redference to anything like beer. It might be somewhere else, though. The problem is finding it...

Answer (score 0):

I finally got through this. In config table in the database there was (probably just from some test long ago) a reference to that example.

Deleting that line made the updates to go through.

Now checking if it solved my actual problem...

Thanks for the help

hank